# I have to move my logs from one server to another server on a weekly basis using a shell script

Tags: shell

I am having a new sever and i want to move all my logs file from the old server to the new server on a weekly basis.

If the directory is not exist then create a directory of that week and transfer all the files of that week from the old server to the new one.

I am not able to find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a cron job that triggers once every week. [See this tutorial](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial).
2. In your cron command, you write a copy (and optionally delete) command

   ```
      scp -i private_key remote_server_address:/path/to/paste/log/dir; rm -rf /path/to/logfile/on/current/server;
   ```

done.

One thing to note, that I have used private_key to authenticate the connection. [See here how to achieve password less authentication](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/)

Comment: I have already done that but i want to transfer the files on a weekly basis to its week directory not all the files to a single directory.     Like : there are 20 files in total. 10 are of week 1, 7 are of week 2, and 3 are of week 3.    So now i want to structure my log files like this  logs/week1/all this week 1 files,   logs/week1/all this week 2 files

Comment: Or use [**`rsync`**](http://superuser.com/a/349538/37904), from `cron` using passphrase-less authentication, of course.

Comment: echo "Checking If Directory Exists Or Not" 
echo "-----------------------"
ssh -i PATH/private-key                                        server name                                                         'tgt_path=/$PATH
if [ ! -d ${tgt_path} ];
then
mkdir -p ${tgt_path}
fi
echo "Directory Exists"
'

echo "Moving Logs" 
echo "-----------------------"
rsync -r -a -v -e "ssh -i PRIVATE KEY" --delete path1 PATH2
echo "Done"
echo "------------------------"
echo "All Done!"

Comment: well, if you copy and delete log folder every week, the log folder will contains just the previous week's logs. You can copy to remote server with a folder name like `log_2012_02_11`, representing that this folder has log of the week ended on `11 Feb 2012`. What's the issue?